# XMLstarlet for JSON?

Tags: xml, json

Is there a tool that is similar to [XMLstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416) but works on JSON instead of XML?

My usecase: extract certain values from hierarchical JSON documents, as they are returned by some REST APIs.

Something like being able to select a node via an  XPath-like expression would be helpful there.

Comment: This [answer to 'What are good CLI tools for JSON?'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14132863/427158) on Stackoverflow is also relevant.

Comment: Honestly,  I would probably just use perl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[jq provides a rich expression language](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for selecting elements from a JSON document.

Thus, it is similar to the `sel` command of `xmlstartlet` (which takes an XPath expression).

For example, to extract a list of available CentOS 7 kernel versions on digital ocean - in a record format:

```
$ jq '[ .kernels[] | select(.name | test("^CentOS 7 x64")) | del(.name)
        | "\(.version) \(.id)"] | .[]' kernels.json
```

Or the same simplified a little bit:

```
jq '.kernels[] | select(.name | test("^CentOS 7 x64")) |
     "\(.version) \(.id)" ' kernels.json
```

Where the json can be obtained like this:

```
$ curl -o kernels.json -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $bearer" \
 "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/$droplet/kernels?page=1&per_page=1000"
```

There is also [ObjectPath](https://adriank.github.io/ObjectPath/), a different query language for JSON - although jq seems to be wider available (e.g. it is packaged on Fedora 23).

Re-using such query snippets in programs is easily possible, e.g. there are multiple bindings for jq (e.g. [for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq/)) and ObjectPath is also available as Python module.